# Clojure lazy-eval inside apply

Tags: clojure, eval, lazy-evaluation, take

I'm trying to read in a file line by line and concatenate a new string to the end of each line. For testing I've done this:

```
(defn read-file
[filename]
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
  (doall (line-seq rdr))))

(apply str ["asdfasdf" (doall (take 1 (read-file filename)))])
```

If I just evaluate `(take 1 (read-file filename))` in a repl, I get the first line of the file. However, when I try to evaluate what I did above, I get `"asdfasdfclojure.lang.LazySeq@4be5d1db"`.

Can anyone explain how to forcefully evaluate `take` to get it to not return the lazy sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `take` function is lazy by design, so you may have to realize the values you want, using `first`, `next`, or `nth`, or operate on the entire seq with functions like `apply`, `reduce`, `vec`, or `into`.

In your case, it looks like you are trying to do the following:

```
(apply str ["asdfasdf" (apply str (take 1 (read-file filename)))])
```

Or:

```
(str "asdfasdf" (first (read-file filename)))
```

You can also realize the entire lazyseq using `doall`. Just keep in mind, a realized lazy seq is still a seq.

```
(realized? (take 1 (read-file filename))) ;; => false
(type (take 1 (read-file filename))) ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq

(realized? (doall (take 1 (read-file filename)))) ;; => true
(type (doall (take 1 (read-file filename)))) ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

A better option would be to apply your transformations lazily, using something like [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map), and select the values you want from the resulting seq. (Like stream processing.)

```
(first (map #(str "prefix" % "suffix")
             (read-file filename)))
```

**Note:** [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) is lazy, so it will return an unrealized LazySeq.

Comment: That works, thanks. I have to ask though, the docstring for doall says that it forces lazy evaluation of functions, however, when I do `(apply str ["asdfasdf" (doall (take 1 (read-file filename)))])` I still get lazyseq. Can you explain this?

Comment: A lazyseq can be realized without converting to another type. `doall` realizes the entire seq, but you still have to treat it like a seq.

Comment: Thanks that clears things up, I was thinking it was something like that, but understanding clojure's docstrings is a talent in and of itself I think :)